# how to call "boost::remove_vertex" without re-indexing the vertices?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I noticed that if I call `boost::remove_vertex`, the vertices are re-indexed to start from zero.

For example:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::adjacency_list<> g;

  boost::add_vertex(g);
  boost::add_vertex(g);
  boost::add_vertex(g);
  boost::add_vertex(g);

  boost::remove_vertex(0, g); // remove vertex 0

  std::pair<boost::adjacency_list<>::vertex_iterator,
            boost::adjacency_list<>::vertex_iterator> vs = boost::vertices(g);

  std::copy(vs.first, vs.second,
            std::ostream_iterator<boost::adjacency_list<>::vertex_descriptor>{
              std::cout, "\n"
                });
  // expects: 1, 2 and 3
  // actual: 0, 1 and 2, I suspect re-indexing happened.
}
```

I'm wondering how to make the above code outputs 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the vertex index invalidation is the default for vertex container selector (`VertexListS`) of the `adjacency_list` template.

```
  template <class OutEdgeListS = vecS,
        class VertexListS = vecS,
        class DirectedS = directedS,
        ...
  class adjacency_list {};
```

When you invoke `remove_vertex` for `adjacency_list` which has `VertexListS` as `vecS` all iterators and descriptors for the graph are invalidated.

To avoid invalidating descriptors you can use `listS` instead `vecS` as `VertexListS`. If you use `listS`, you won't get an implicit `vertex_index` because the descriptor is not a suitable integral type. Instead for `listS` you will an opaque vertex descriptor type (that the implementation can translate back into a list element reference or iterator).

This is why you should use `vertex_descriptor` for referring to a vertex.
So you can write

```
 typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::listS> graph;
 graph g;

 graph::vertex_descriptor desc1 = boost::add_vertex(g);
 boost::add_vertex(g);
 boost::add_vertex(g);
 boost::add_vertex(g);

 boost::remove_vertex(desc1, g);

 std::pair<graph::vertex_iterator,
        graph::vertex_iterator> vs = boost::vertices(g);

 std::copy(vs.first, vs.second,
        std::ostream_iterator<graph::vertex_descriptor>{
          std::cout, "\n"
            });
```