# Have a DAG graph in boost without vertex descriptor invalidation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to implement a direct acyclic graph with the `boost::adjacency_list<>` class. For that I re-implemented the idea from this question: [boost graph that doesn't allow circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771885/boost-graph-that-doesnt-allow-circular-references)

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
```

With that I was able to call the `topological_sort` after each `add_edge` to confirm I have a DAG:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>

int main()
{
    Graph g;

    // 1. build a graph structure
    auto v1 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    auto v2 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    auto v3 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_edge(v1, v2, g);
    boost::topological_sort(g, boost::make_function_output_iterator([](int) {}));
    boost::add_edge(v2, v3, g);
    boost::topological_sort(g, boost::make_function_output_iterator([](int) {}));
}
```

An additional requirement I have is to enable some undo/redo support on actions I do on my graph. One of the operation could be to remove a vertex and deleting all incoming and outgoing edges from the specified vertex. A sample code could look like this:

```
static void Print(const Graph& g)
{
    std::cout << "Vertices: " << std::endl;
    for (auto vertices = boost::vertices(g); vertices.first != vertices.second; ++vertices.first)
    {
        std::cout << *vertices.first << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Edges: " << std::endl;
    for (auto edges = boost::edges(g); edges.first != edges.second; ++edges.first)
    {
        auto edgeDescriptor = *edges.first;
        std::cout << edgeDescriptor.m_source << "->" << edgeDescriptor.m_target << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Graph g;

    // 1. build a graph structure
    auto v1 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    auto v2 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    auto v3 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_edge(v1, v2, g);
    boost::add_edge(v2, v3, g);
    Print(g);

    // 2. prepare for deletion of v2
    std::vector<Vertex> outVertices;
    for(auto vertices = boost::adjacent_vertices(v2, g); vertices.first != vertices.second; ++vertices.first)
    {
        outVertices.push_back(*vertices.first);
    }
    std::vector<Vertex> inVertices;
    for (auto vertices = boost::inv_adjacent_vertices(v2, g); vertices.first != vertices.second; ++vertices.first)
    {
        inVertices.push_back(*vertices.first);
    }

    // 3. delete v2
    boost::clear_vertex(v2, g);
    boost::remove_vertex(v2, g);
    Print(g);

    // 4 undo the operation
    v2 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    for(auto& outVertex : outVertices)
    {
        boost::add_edge(v2, outVertex, g);
    }

    for (auto& inVertex : inVertices)
    {
        boost::add_edge(inVertex, v2, g);
    }
    Print(g);
}
```

Output:

```
Vertices:
0
1
2
Edges:
0->1
1->2

Vertices:
0
1
Edges:

Vertices:
0
1
2
Edges:
2->2
0->2
```

This doesn't work of course because the `remove_vertex` call invalidates my earlier saved `vertex_descriptors`. A solution I found for this problem was [how to call "boost::remove_vertex" without re-indexing the vertices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066299/how-to-call-boostremove-vertex-without-re-indexing-the-vertices)

Here it proposed to use a list instead of a vector for saving the vertices and therefore the `vertex_descriptors` do not get invalidated.

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS>;
```

This does work as expected and gives the desired output where the undo works:

```
Vertices:
000001DD1902AC90
000001DD19028F70
000001DD19028D80
Edges:
000001DD1902AC90->000001DD19028F70
000001DD19028F70->000001DD19028D80

Vertices:
000001DD1902AC90
000001DD19028D80
Edges:

Vertices:
000001DD1902AC90
000001DD19028D80
000001DD19028F70
Edges:
000001DD19028F70->000001DD19028D80
000001DD1902AC90->000001DD19028F70
```

The problem I have now is that the `topological_sort` does not compile anymore with my new `Graph` definition. For full error message: https://godbolt.org/z/WKjeK3ddP

The question I have (or the problem I am trying to solve is) how can I implement a direct acyclic graph in boost without invalidating the `vertex_descriptors` while removing vertices and having the `topological_sort` possibility?

Or maybe not that specific: How to impelement a DAG with boost on where I can enable/implement undo/redo possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question.

### The topological sort

It fails because there's no longer an implicit vertex index. Topological sort requires it to get a default color map, so things that work:

```
std::map<Vertex, int> index;
for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
    index.emplace(v, index.size());

boost::topological_sort(
    g, boost::make_function_output_iterator([](Vertex) {}),
    boost::vertex_index_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(index)));
```

Or, just provide a color map directly, which is probably a better idea:

```
std::map<Vertex, boost::default_color_type> colors;

boost::topological_sort(
    g, boost::make_function_output_iterator([](Vertex) {}),
    boost::color_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(colors)));
```

> There's some more thinking behind this problem here:
> [What is required for a custom BGL graph to work with topological sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352055/what-is-required-for-a-custom-bgl-graph-to-work-with-topological-sort/66352925#66352925)

### Big Picture

The thing I like most about your question is that after a very high level of detailed analysis, you still go back and wonder whether there's something else. This is you, trying to avoid tunnel vision or X/Y problem.

> Or maybe not that specific: How to impelement a DAG with boost on where I can enable/implement undo/redo possibilities?

To be completely honest, I think you're shoe-horning a very specific datastructure into something BGL should have. And that's just improbable. I'd reverse the design priorities.

BGL is *expressly* designed to be almost completely generic. This means you can use the algorithms on your own data structures given the right instrumentation/adaptation.

Your requirements feel more like a versioned tree/forest. A Sean-Parent-style tree with `shared_ptr<const T>` nodes seems more applicable.

> A quick demonstration of the concept, focusing on Copy-On-Write deep modification of sub-trees: [Transforming trees in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708139/transforming-trees-in-c/27715495#27715495)

A more advanced strategy could be e.g. splay trees, but I'd have to freshen up on theory myself before recommening/implementing anything like that.

Now, all of this doesn't really touch on any requirements for graph algorithms. The linked answer above incidentally shows topological sort on a custom graph model, so you can have a look and see whether that looks viable. At some point you might decide it's better to "just implement" BFS for your own datastructure.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really great and I reconsidered some design choices I made while using the graph library. I am also considering now the use-cases of trees for the prototype I am implementing. Some of the use-cases I have are better modeled with a graph "currently" (in my eyes). But as I tried to understand your very detailed answer, I realized I have to go deeper in theory (graphs/trees, in general data structures, not that much left from university). Can you recommend some literature about data structures?